# Is there a way to block out certain brackets in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is there some way to remove everything in brackets? I want a Notepad++ Script that can do something like this.

```
[0] = {
            ["HumanoidRootPart"] = {
                ["Torso"] = {
                    CFrame = CFrame.new(0, 1.324, -1.83) * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(-56.608), 0, 0),
                    ["Left Leg"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(-6.589), math.rad(2.464), math.rad(-30.023)),
                    },
                    ["Right Arm"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(0, 0, math.rad(-64.229)),
                    },
                    ["Head"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(6.131), 0, 0),
                    },
                    ["Left Arm"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(0, 0, math.rad(53.572)),
                    },
                    ["Right Leg"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(-5.73), math.rad(-2.063), math.rad(27.731)),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        [0.017] = {
            ["HumanoidRootPart"] = {
                ["Torso"] = {
                    CFrame = CFrame.new(0, 1.324, -1.83) * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(-56.608), 0, 0),
                    ["Left Leg"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(-6.589), math.rad(2.464), math.rad(-30.023)),
                    },
                    ["Right Arm"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(0, 0, math.rad(-64.229)),
                    },
                    ["Head"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(6.131), 0, 0),
                    },
                    ["Left Arm"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(0, 0, math.rad(53.572)),
                    },
                    ["Right Leg"] = {
                        CFrame = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(-5.73), math.rad(-2.063), math.rad(27.731)),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
```

To this:

```
RunAnim(0)
RunAnim(0.017)
```

This would be really helpful for me, im currently making an animation script for my game using CFrame.
Basically just taking the numbers and adding RunAnim. I got through 1 of them until I realized I should go here to ask for help.
Thanks!

-reidlab

Comment: To clarify, you are looking to extract numbers between `[` and `]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to capture the digits between the square brackets at the start of the string only in group 1 and then use that group in the replacement.

To prevent unnecessary backtracking, you can match all following lines using a negative lookahead asserting that the string does not start with a digit part between square brackets.

**Find what:**

```
^\h*\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)].*(?:\R(?!\h*\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?]).*)*
```

**Replace with:**

```
RunAnim\($1\)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\[` Match opening `[`

  - `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `]` Match closing `]`
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\R` Match any unicode newline sequence
  - `(?!\h*\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?])` Negative lookahead, assert that the line does not start with a digit between `[]`
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close group and repeat it 0+ times to match all lines

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2kafyQ/1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace, with dot all mode enabled from NPP:

```
Find:    \[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\].*?(?=\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?\]|$)
Replace: RunAnim($1)\n
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
\[(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\]      match e.g. [0.017] and capture in $1
.*?                      then match all content up to,
                         but not including,
(?=\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?\]|$)  the next number OR the end of the input
```